# Excel VBA fails to read web source over 40,000 characters

Tags: excel, vba, buffer

Trying to receive website source code via Excel VBA works for approximately 4000 words, 40000 chars. Then it stops. And I don't know why.

Can anyone help me?

```
Option Explicit
Private Const INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE = &H4000000
Private Declare Function InternetOpen Lib "Wininet.dll" Alias "InternetOpenA" (ByVal lpszAgent As String, ByVal dwAccessType As Long, ByVal lpszProxyName As String, ByVal lpszProxyBypass As String, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function InternetReadFile Lib "Wininet.dll" (ByVal hFile As Long, ByVal sBuffer As String, ByVal lNumBytesToRead As Long, lNumberOfBytesRead As Long) As Integer
Private Declare Function InternetOpenUrl Lib "Wininet.dll" Alias "InternetOpenUrlA" (ByVal hInternetSession As Long, ByVal sUrl As String, ByVal sHeaders As String, ByVal lHeadersLength As Long, ByVal lFlags As Long, ByVal lContext As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function InternetCloseHandle Lib "Wininet.dll" (ByVal hInet As Long) As Integer

Public Sub GetWebPageData()

  Dim hInternet, hSession, lngDataReturned As Long
  Dim iReadFileResult As Integer
  Dim sBuffer As String * 64
  Dim sTotalData As String
  Dim sUrl As String
  Dim sLine As String

  sUrl = "http://www.engadget.com/" 'Long Website here
  hSession = InternetOpen("", 0, vbNullString, vbNullString, 0)

  If hSession Then hInternet = InternetOpenUrl(hSession, sUrl, vbNullString, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE, 0)

  If hInternet Then
    iReadFileResult = InternetReadFile(hInternet, sBuffer, 128, lngDataReturned)

    sTotalData = sBuffer

    Do While lngDataReturned <> 0
      iReadFileResult = InternetReadFile(hInternet, sBuffer, 128, lngDataReturned)
      sTotalData = sTotalData + Mid(sBuffer, 1, lngDataReturned)
    Loop
  End If

  iReadFileResult = InternetCloseHandle(hInternet)

  'WEBPAGE loaded into sTotalData
  Cells(2, 2) = sTotalData
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm intrigued as to why you're using this method, I queried the same page using a standard XMLHTTP request and it was faster and the final string had twice the amount of data, the data returned by this code made no sense on my machine, though I'm using 64-bit if that makes any difference.

Comment: Can you show me any code? I just found two methods (1.open IExplorer in VBA, wait and close which is very slow, 2. my method). I'm thankful for any help to speed up my program ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the line

```
Cells(2, 2) = sTotalData
```

Returning a string to a cell is limnited to 32767 characters in Excel 2007/2010, even if `sTotalData` is longer than that.

Refer to [this link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010342495.aspx)

Comment: Didn't have the time to proof it, but sounds very good. Thanks to you, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As requested, another way of getting the full source code:

```
Function GetSource(url As String) As String

With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", url
    .Send
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until .Readystate = 4
    GetSource = .responsetext
    .abort
End With

End Function
```

Comment: Hey, I was searching for a solution to receive html source in vba for more than one week. Found nothing fast enough. And your code is like: easy, easy, only 10 lines of code, easy... Thank you very much! Hope, people searching for that will find this Answer!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried :

```
For i = 1 To Len(sTotalData) Step (Len(sTotalData) /  200) '*Line1 of 3 to replace Cells(2, 2) = sTotalData


Cells(i \ (Len(sTotalData) / 200) + 1, "A").Value = "'" & Mid(sTotalData, i, (Len(sTotalData) / 200)) '*Line2 of 3 to replace Cells(2, 2) = sTotalData


Next i '*Line3 of 3 to replace Cells(2, 2) = sTotalData
```